# Histogram Equalization in Video

Tags: python, opencv, video, python-imaging-library, histogram

I wish to apply the technique of histogram equalization to a captured video using Python Image Library and OpenCV. But I looked online for resources or possible techniques regarding this topic but came up with nothing. Is it possible to perform frame by frame histogram equalization of a video and then reconstruct the frames back to obtain the equalized video? Or if there is an alternative technique to do it then please suggest some links. I understand that it will be extremely resource intensive but that is not an issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible to perform frame by frame histogram equalization of a video and then reconstruct the frames back to obtain the equalized video? Yes.

Comment: @AbidRahmanK Could you provide links or suggest techniques to perform it using python image library and OpenCV

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to perform frame by frame histogram equalization of a
>   video and then reconstruct the frames back to obtain the equalized
>   video?

Yes

1. [Read a video frame-by-frame](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#playing-video-from-file)
2. [Histogram Equalization of the frame](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_histograms/py_histogram_equalization/py_histogram_equalization.html#py-histogram-equalization)
3. [Write the video back](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#saving-a-video)

But one thing, I am not sure whether the output is really the one you want. I am just saying, it is possible to read a video frame-by-frame, equalize its histogram and write it back to a video. I don't know if that is a real "histogram equalized video"

Comment: Can you please give the present links for the above mentioned links as those links are not present now ?